# How to apply CSS to body tag in a child Div using SASS?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, scss-mixins

The scenario is I want to add CSS style for `<body>` on a child DIV

Whenever a DIV with a Fixed position is displayed, overflow will be hidden on the Body

```
.fixedDiv {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 50vh;
      body {
       overflow: hidden
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sass will always compile to css, so you always should ask yourself how to do it in css first.

What you are trying to achieve can be done using the [:has pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

```css
body:has(.fixedDiv) {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

But at the time of writing, this selector is [not yet fully supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has) by all major browsers. For Firefox it is still behind an experimental flag.

So I recommend to avoid using it for production projects yet. I am sure there is an alternative way of approaching the goal you are trying to achieve with a different layout.

Answer (score -2):

it will be nice if you use the embedded css style attribute

or

the internal css way

.fixedDiv {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 50vh;
      body {
       overflow: hidden
      }
}